# Can Git be made to preserve HFS+ extended attributes?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

Is there any way to make Git preserve HFS+ extended attributes?  All I can think of is some Rube-Goldberg system where I use a commit hook script that reads the extended attributes from the file and records them somewhere else, and a checkout hook script that later applies them when checking out. But I'm hoping there's an easier way.

And yes I realize this is slightly outside of the scope of what Git is really designed for.  But since it is so incredibly powerful (and in some ways quite flexible) I'm hoping there's a way to do this.

Comment: Those hooks are part of its power.  Nothing untoward about scripting what you want.

Comment: Yes, and part of its flexibility, but it would be much easier if there were a way to let Git itself maintain the attributes, rather than creating scripts to serialize and deserialize them.

Comment: @iconoclast Did you make anything? :)

Comment: @HappyFace no, not yet....

Comment: @iconoclast I ended up using tagbak. It works great.